# Add Layer from Database or Datatable to Basemap using Esri.ArcGISRuntime in C#

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

How can I add/create Layer using Datatable or Database Query in C#.net instead adding through Uri using Esri.ArcGISRuntime sdk?

Comment: What is Uri, did you meant URL?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box support for this. Typically you'd publish your data as a feature service (backed by the database) that you would then connect to via its REST interface. Another approach is to export the data to a "runtime geodatabase" (which is really just a sqlite database with a very specific schema) and you can load that directly into your map as well.

You could make your own database queries, parse the fields and geometry data and populate a FeatureCollectionTable or GraphicsOverlay but it would be a bit more involved on your end.
I do have a repo here that has some code for converting geometries from various formats (including Sql Server geometry) into Runtime Geometry to get you started: https://github.com/dotMorten/GeometryConversions